# InputStream returns -1 before end of file

Tags: java

I'm streaming a file from a server and then streaming it back out to a socket (basically a stream proxy).  This is being used to buffer a song.  So once the buffer is full, no more data is read from the socket until the buffer empties out.  However, once more data is read, the InputStream will read X more bytes, then suddenly return a -1 signaling the end of the file, when it is not.  Is there a timeout that is happening?

Here's some example code:

```
  InputStream data = realResponse.getEntity().getContent();

  ...some code...

  int totalBytes = 0;
  int count = 0;
  // Start streaming content.
  byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 50];
  while (isRunning && (readBytes = data.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
    totalBytes += readBytes;

    Log(count + ": buffer:" + buff + " readBytes:" + readBytes + " total:" + totalBytes);
    client.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, readBytes);
    Log("Finished write");
    count++;          

  }
```

An example of the log would look like:

```
0: buffer:B@45030a50 readBytes: 16164 total: 16164
1: buffer:B@45030a50 readBytes: 16384 total: 32548
...
100: buffer:B@45030a50 readBytes: 16384 total: 1654564
<a long pause here>
100: buffer:B@45030a50 readBytes: 16384 total: 1670948
100: buffer:B@45030a50 readBytes: 16384 total: 1687332
-1 Received
```

Any help or suggestions are appreciate

Comment: The log above does not seem to match up with the code.  There are no "Finished write" messages in the log, and there is no code that logs "-1 Received."  Is `readBytes` defined in the scope of `totalBytes`?  Where is `count` set?  Is there a relationship between `count` and `readBytes`?

Comment: I cleaned the logs up a little and took out "Finished write" just for readability sake, but forgot to take it out of the code.  The "-1 Received" is in a log statement that is not shown.  readBytes, totalBytes, and count are all within scope.  The count variable is simply for debugging how many read/writes have been done.

Comment: What about that 'isRunning" boolean check?  Is this a multi threaded app?  Could something be setting that flag to false?

Comment: No, I check the readBytes after the loop and it is indeed a -1.  The totalBytes is also less than the content-length in the header.  This functionality is running in its own thread, so nothing would be setting isRunning to false.  Thanks.

Comment: Does it stop in the exact same place every time?  If it does, open the file in something like UltraEdit32 and look at the hex values.  You should be able to see if there is something around that mark that would cause an EOF notification.  It might not be your code, but the file itself.  Have you tried other files?  Same results?

Comment: The file does not stop in the same place every time, which makes it that much harder to debug.  I have tried multiple other files and get the same result.  However, if I have a slower connection and the max buffer is not hit and therefore there is no long pause, the entire file will download fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read() returns -1 at end of stream and not before. If you are getting -1 earlier than expected, the data is shorter than expected, or the server is closing his end earlier than expected.

Comment: I assume the server is closing the connection after data is not read from it for potentially a couple of minutes.  What would the proper way be to reopen the connection and continue reading?  Would setting the Range header be an acceptable solution?  Or is it possible to keep the connection open for longer?  Thanks.

Comment: @Nick: If you're using HTTP the Range header may work, depending on your server. The real question is why the pause? What are you writing to? Is it buffered? Is it a socket? if so, does it have a large socket send buffer? and what's at the other end? and why is *it* stalling? and are you really getting 16384 bytes at a time?

Comment: I've been trying to work with the Range header, however, I'm still working on it and having a few issues.  The pause happens because the receiving ends buffer has become full and therefore can not accept any more data.  I am writing to a socket but in this case does it matter how big the sockets send buffer is since it is the buffer on the receiving end that is filling up?  The other end that is receiving the data is a MediaPlayer class on a mobile device which is trying to use a small amount of memory and therefore the small buffer and stalling.  And yes, I am actually getting 16483 bytes.

Comment: This problem also happened to me when using the InputStream object returned by java.util.ZipFile.

Comment: Anyhow does anybody know how to make IO block even if end of file is reached? You know, until all bytes I requested have been read.