# InputStream doens't read the whole answer of an URL connection

Tags: java, android, url, inputstream

I'm struggling against the uncompleted download of a file.

For example, I upload some data on github :https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rdanniau/3b7f26bb1101b28400bf24f2f9664828/raw/980d6ff511404bf14d3efc56be3dfb081541991f/LEDirium.hex

and on pasteBin : http://pastebin.com/raw/FcVfLf5b

I want to retrieve them and save them into a file "filename".
I've watch a lot of example on internet and it must be working.

Here is the code :

```
    private void download(final URL myUrl){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        //InputStream is = null;
        //FileOutputStream fos = null;
        public void run() {
            try {
                URLConnection connection = myURLL.openConnection();
                //HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
                //connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                connection.connect();

                //is = myUrl.openStream();
                is = connection.getInputStream();
                File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(),fileName);
                file.delete();
                file = new File(context.getFilesDir(),fileName);
                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                String str ="";
                int count = 0;
                while ((count = is.read(data)) != -1) {
                    fos.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                is.close();
                fos.close();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                downloadedFileCallback.onError(e);
                Log.e("DownloadedFile", "Unable to download : " + e.getMessage() + " cause :" + e.getCause());
                return;
            }
            downloadedFileCallback.onDownloadedFinished();
            readFile(context);
        }
    }).start();
}
public void readFile(Context context){
    // read
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(context.getFilesDir(),fileName)));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            Log.v("DL", line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DownloadedFile", "Unable to read : " + e.getMessage() + " cause :" + e.getCause());
    }
    //Log.v("DownloadedFile", text.toString());
}
```

where myURL are called like

```
  URL myURL = new URL("http://pastebin.com/raw/FcVfLf5b");
```

In the Log.v, I can see that I downloaded only a part of the file which is never the same (it could be the entire file, the half, the quarter, we don' know...)

It's probably the inputStream connection which is closed too fast. But why ?
Last question, instead of using Log.v to check if the file is correctly downloaded. Where can I found it on my phone ? I searched in many folders but I never seen my File.

Thanks a lot for any advice

EDIT : It seems to be the same here [InputStream returns -1 before end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958671/inputstream-returns-1-before-end-of-file) but no one answered.